# Where does CodeGear Delphi 2009 store settings

Tags: delphi, configuration, settings, delphi-2009

I'm running windows 7 ultimate (32bit) and have a very anoying problem with my installation of delphi.

The problem is with the feature "Code Insight" and with "Code template completion", it is very anoying when it every time i write something and it wants to complete some piece of code for me (for example i hate it when he completes the for condition). The problem is that i can't shut it down since i think it has a bug when installed on windows 7 that when i turn those features off it works once and then it turns on again, like it couldn't write in the settings file.

Does anybody know where Codegear Delphi 2009 stores it's setting/configuration file? Or how can i turn off.
I tried running it as administrator in compatibility mode (vista and xp) tried searching for the file but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the registry under: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0
Also in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\6.0 but there seems to be no data there of interest.
Also under C:\Users*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\CodeGear\BDS\6.0 are some settings stored.

Comment: i didn't check the registry keys, but i did check the c:\Users folder and didn't find anything usefull... i just hope it doesn't store user settings in a binary file

Comment: Actually, those settings are indeed stored in those registry branches... Code Insight is found in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\Code Insight" but changing those values does nothing :(

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\Code Insight\Borland.EditOptions.Pascal" and there are the settings stored and editing them helped :)